# regex to extract lookbehind and lookahead from a regex pattern

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I have an unusual application whereby I need to extract the content of lookbehind and lookahead portions of a regex pattern (using regex of course!). For example in the following pattern:

```
(?<=(?:c|d))123(?=(?:x|y))
```

matches the first `123` in the following string:

```
abc123xyz123xyz
```

What I need is to extract the following strings:

```
(?:c|d)
```

and

```
(?:x|y)
```

It is proving hard because I can't easily find the correct closing brackets as there could be other brackets as in the example.

Just wondering if anyone has had to do this before. Any thoughts welcome

Comment: If you can access the value of the capturing groups in the lookarounds you could turn the non capturing groups into capturing ones and use a character class to match a single char instead of an alternation `(?<=([cd]))123(?=([xy]))` https://regex101.com/r/zBM7sn/1

Comment: Imagine a regex like: `(?<=\([abc]\)(?![aeiou])[a-z]\(\))blah(?=[xyz](?:(abc|def)ghi))`, I think you should write a parser.

Comment: For PCRE, something like `(?s)(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*\K\(\?:(?:[^\\()]|\\.|(\((?:[^()]++|(?1))*\)))*\)` would help. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/ijDMH0/2). In .NET, replace `(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*\K` with `(?<=(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*)`

Comment: Forth Bird. Thanks. I could do that but unfortunately I am still left with the problem of finding the correct matching closing bracket.

Comment: I am trying to understand the solution of Wiktor. Pretty complex! I split it into lines here: https://regex101.com/r/ijDMH0/3 with comments. I can't work out what is going in the main (long) line. Any comments on that welcome. Also pls note that the content of the lookaround is general and need not have brackets. The third line I have added is not matched by Wiktor's solution.

Comment: @Kaveh1000, I've tried to provide an answer to this regex which was puzzling you. And me. I did not know what `++` is, but now it's a bit clearer to me, and maybe it can make things clearer to you too.

Comment: Thank you so much @EnricoMariaDeAngelis for the clear explanation. I still haven't got it but I will now work on it to understand ++ that I had not used before.

Comment: @Kaveh1000, I've updated the answer to better explain what `++` is. Please, give a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments to the question, my understanding is that the asker Kaveh1000 is happy with Wiktor's solution; however it seems he's puzzled by one part of that solution

```
(\((?:[^()]++|(?1))*\))
```

In this respect, I suggest to read [Mastering Regular Expressions, 3rd Edition's](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596528126.do), which dedicates a lot of words to this topic (and specifically to this very regex); I've just read it from there now, and in the following I try to convey my understanding:

1. it is a capturing group `(…)` to which we can refer if we need (and we do indeed in 4.2.);
2. it matches a pair of literal parethesis with something in between `\(…\)`;
3. that something in between, `(?:…)*`, is the sequence of 0 or more (ordinary greedy) non-captured expressions;
4. each of those 0 or more repetions can be either

   4.1. a sequence of 0 or more non-parenthesis, `[^()]++`,

   4.2. or something, `(?1)`, which matches the same regex we are matching now (point 1); this is the recursiveness of the regex.

Two notes:

- The literal parenthesis appear in (this part of) the regex only through `\(` and `\)`, which are ordered (opening first, then closing) and both have to match; this guarantees that this part of the regex will match balanced parethesis only.
- `++` is necessary because if the regex is `((something)+)*` there are many ways to assign a number of repetions to `+` and `*`, and all of them have to be tried; `++` instead of `+` will match as much as possible, as it was alone in `(something)+`, and only then the `*` takes effect.
- But what is `++` by itself? I mean, what is `++` beyond the reason why it's necessary in this regex? One easy way to isolate and clearly see the effect of `++` as compared to `+` is to compare how the regexes `a+ab` and `a++ab` behave with a line containing `aaaaaab`. The former will match the whole line, with `a+` matching the first 5 `a`s, and `ab` matching the last two characters; the latter will not match, as `a++` matches as many `a`s as possible without giving up in favour of the rest of the regex, thus matching all 6 `a`, without leaving any chance for `ab` to match after it and, eventually, leading to a match failure.